# Был недавно в FARШе

Tags: окончания, аббревиатуры, латиница-кириллица, апостроф

Кому что известно о правилах склонения иноязычных аббревиатур? В заглавии приведена смешанная, а вообще — можно ли приписывать им окончания, и в каких случаях?

Comment: Но это не аббревиатура.

Comment: Это... (дальше идёт нецензурная брань)

Comment: Да, вы правы, не аббревиатура. Тем не менее, интересно узнать, приписывается ли к таким словам окончание.

Comment: Я полагаю, приписывается. Это ведь обычное слово русского языка, просто набранное, ради стилизации, вперемешку кириллицей и латиницей.

Comment: После "тем не менее" не нужна запятая.

Answer (score 3):

Начну с конца: приписать окончание аббревиатуре можно, если она произносится как слово, а не побуквенно (то есть, например, нельзя приписать окончание к *СССР* или *ФРГ*). Окончания приписываются строчными буквами, без отделения: *ТАССа*, *МИДом* (см. § 113 ныне действующих Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации за 1956 г.).

Теперь отвечаю на первый вопрос: склонять иноязычные аббревиатуры можно, если они соответствуют вышеприведённому правилу, то есть произносятся целым словом. При этом окончание отделяется от аббревиатуры апострофом — по общему принципу отделения кириллического суффикса/окончания от некириллической части слова: ***Он инструментовал сочиненную летом c-moll’ную увертюру** (Берб.)* (см. [справочник Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=61)).